# How to place code for like button when no access to code on my webpage

Tags: html, facebook-like

My websites are generated by vistaprint and facebook, so I have no access to the html. So how can I add the code which is provided to me for the Facebook like button?

Comment: Poorly worded. Updating.

Comment: @tekknolagi: I fixed your edit. She was not asking how to **get** the code, but how to **add** it to her page.

Comment: It sounded more like "where can I find the code"

Answer (score 2):

After a quick google search:

> On your VistaPrint dashboard, go to insert extras, click on HTML and paste in the HTML code you got from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

It's on developers.facebook.com and you just need to poke around for the Like button.

EDIT:
Or just Google it. First result for `facebook like button`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

To customize and get code.

Comment: It sounds like he already has the code, he just doesn't know where to put it.